# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused Laravel 5.8.35

Tags: database, laravel, mamp, laravel-artisan

Using Mac OS X, MAMP 5.5 and Laravel 5.8.35

When I use 'php artisan migrate' I get the following error message:

Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = auth and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/auth/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664

```
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668|
```

file .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=auth
DB_USERNAME=etn
DB_PASSWORD=pass
```

the same thing with

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=auth
DB_USERNAME=etn
DB_PASSWORD=pass
```

migrarion file

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

second migration file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePasswordResetsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('password_resets', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('email')->index();
            $table->string('token');
            $table->timestamp('created_at')->nullable();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('password_resets');
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: yes, both with php artisan config:cache and php artisan config:clear

Comment: share your query in migration file

Comment: are you sure your database already running? Connection refused mean your app failed to connect to the database

Comment: @SalunkeAkash added

Comment: @DanieleMastroberti check if your xampp/MAMP is running.

Comment: @azisuazusa i have create a new database in phpmyadmin and i create a new user, how can i verify the correct connection?

Comment: @DanieleMastroberti you can manually connect to the database using MySQL CLI

Comment: open command prompt login to your root account and run SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'port';

Comment: @SalunkeAkash mysql> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'port';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| port          | 8889  |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this changes

```
  DB_PORT=33060
```

Or

```
 DB_PORT=8889
```

Stop and restart server after changes.

Comment: Thank, i have also changed to the in config/database.php 'port' => env('DB_PORT', '8889'),

Comment: hi! did this work? why?

Answer (score 1):

One of its cause, that the server XAMPP has not been started try to check the server that you started it accurately or no at your local host.